# iOs memory stress test

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I'm trying to simulate the behaviour of a component under heavy memory load.

The main idea is to allocate a bunch of memory, keep it resident, then work with my component, however no matter what I do, the memory I allocate on purpose seem do disappear somehow.

After a first test using a strong NSArray of NSData chunks (1Mb each), I tried with a rougher but lower level approach (to prevent some ARC magic to happen):

```
// somewhere after the includes
static char *foo[MAX_CHUNKS];

[...]

// this function is actually called, I checked :)
- (void) allocateMemoryChunks:(int) chunks ofSize:(long) bytes {
    for(int i = 0; i < chunks; ++i) {
        foo[i] = (char *) malloc(bytes);
    }
}
```

No matter what I set for `chunks` and `bytes`, as long as the memory can be allocated, it 'disappears' from the memory count in Xcode and leaves me with the usual meager 2Mb consumed by the application (I'm talking of allocations in the range of 400 chunks of 1024 * 1024 bytes, or 1 chunk of 400 * 1024 * 1024 bytes, for what's worth...).

The memory is clearly outside the reach of ARC (I'm using plain C mallocs!) yet, I can't see it (note that the same happened when I used NSData and NSArray to hold the data).

Where does that memory go? What am I forgetting?

Thank you!

**Addendum**

For the records, the ARC version of the allocateMemoryChunks is:

```
- (void) allocateMemoryChunks2:(int) nchunks ofSize:(long) bytes {
    self.allocated = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:nchunks];
        for(int i = 0; i < nchunks; ++i) {
        char *tmpraw = (char *) malloc(bytes);
        NSData *tmp = [NSData dataWithBytes:tmpraw length:bytes];
        [self.allocated addObject:tmp];
        free(tmpraw);
    }
}
```

with `allocated` declared as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allocated;
```

Comment: You can try to load lots of images for stress test

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out. Still, even if only for academical reasons, I'd like to know why my approach doesn't work